# Need help with modeling the cross-guard of a sword

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have the hilt of the sword and the blade I feel confident I can make but I can't figure out the best way to model this cross-guard and the angles on the faces.

I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers for modeling something like this because i'm kind of stumped at the moment.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've tried something, tell me if this is what you want:

[image]

Comment: I like the wordless style .. we'll see how it goes down.. :)

Comment: I put an "etc" at the end  :o   actually I thought it didn't need any explanation  ;)

Comment: This might be exactly what I was looking for! I'll have to try it. I mainly was having trouble getting the shape down and this might be the way to do it.